# What does func means in R-Format instruction set?

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture, machine-code

I am very new to **Assembly language**. I was reading about **MIPS** architecture and I am stuck with the last field of the **Register Format (R-Format)**. Here is its visual representation,
[image]
Can anyone please help me out with **what does the sixth field means** and how do we calculate it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the description mentions all R-type instructions (e.g. `ADD`, `AND`, `SLL` and others) have  the 6 most significant bits (= op) set to 0, that means the only way to distinguish between them is to look at the 6 least significant bits (= funct). In other words they determine the instruction type. Perhaps an example will help:

```
ADD $1, $2, $3
```

has:

```
op = 0 (as all R-type instructions)
rs = 2
rt = 3
rd = 1
shamt = 0
funct = 0x20 = 0b00000100000 = 32
```

The encoding will thus be:

```
0000 0000 0100 0011 0000 1000 0010 0000
```

For e.g. `XOR` (another R-type) instruction funct is `0b100110 = 0x26 = 38`. So you "calculate" it by looking up what instruction you want to encode.

(taken from [MIPS Instruction Reference](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html)).

Comment: Can you please explain how did you get func = 0x20?

Comment: @JustAnotherProgrammer: I looked it up in a table (like the one arsane [linked](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MIPS_Assembly/Instruction_Formats#Opcodes) to). Funct for `add` is `0x20`.

Comment: Does this relate to the ALUop control signal?

Comment: @KennethWorden: You should start a new question and remember to include info about what specific "ALUop" control signal you're referring to (if you're referencing e.g. COD by Patterson et al. please include edition and page)

Comment: @KennyWorden: In a simple MIPS implementation, yes.  MIPS machine code is intentionally designed so fields of the instruction word could be used *directly* as internal control signals, with minimal "decoding".  If you look at a block diagram of a simple MIPS, it probably routes that part of the instruction word directly to the ALU's control input.

Answer (score 3):

From following table:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MIPS_Assembly/Instruction_Formats#Opcodes

Almost All R-Type instruction's opcode is 00, so the funct select the ALU function.

> Funct
>       For instructions that share an opcode, the funct parameter
>   contains the necessary control codes to differentiate the different
>   instructions. 6 bits long (0 to 5). Example: Opcode 0x00 accesses the
>   ALU, and the funct selects which ALU function to use.